# Rails: update custom attribute by re-rendering partial via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a custom field `phone` for a `User` that is not stored in the database, since I'm using it for other purposes. Each field is in a different partial and can be updated on it's own via AJAX. This is how I handle this in the UsersController:

*app/controllers/users_controller.rb*

```
def update
  @user = ...
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {html: render_to_string partial: 'edit_field', locals: { user: @user }} }
    end
  end
end
```

I have the submitted `phone` param available in a custom User model attribute `custom_attrs`:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
include UserConcern
...
attr_accessor :custom_attrs
...
# I've shorten this method, so that you can get the idea, might not work in reality
def update_attributes
  self.custom_attrs[:phone] = self.phone
end
```

I can't add that to the `@user` object before I return the response in the controller, I get `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'phone'`.

In my view the `phone` field value is set by a method in the UserConcern:

*app/models/concerns/user_concern.rb*

```
def phone
  self.phone = fetch_phone(user) # this method returns the users' phone value
end
```

When I update the phone and re-render the partial, it still has the same value, because the `@user` object doesn't have `phone`, since it's not a field in the model.

I also can't do `send("phone=", value)`, because there's no such method in the controller (results in `NoMethodError: undefined method 'phone_number_mobile=' for #<UsersController:`)

So - how do set the value for `phone` to the newly updated object `@user`, either by the `@user.custom_attrs` or the UserConcern?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way.

app/models/user.rb

```
...
attr_accessor :phone
...
```

You can then access user.phone

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that for other reasons. I can only store those fields in the `:custom_attrs`

Comment: What do are you using? What version of Rails?

Comment: Depending on your rails version, there are different solutions. If you could let me know the Rails version you are using, I can Taylor my answer to help you.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4